# HTTP/1ではHostリクエストヘッダは必須ですが、HTTP/2ではオプショナルなのでしょうか？

Tags: http

## 環境

- Chrome 97.0.4692.71（Official Build） （64 ビット）
- Firefox 95.0.2 (64-bit)

## HTTPのHostリクエストヘッダについて

以下のサイトを読み、HTTPのHostリクエストヘッダはHTTP/1.1では必須であることを理解しました。
https://www.tohoho-web.com/ex/http.htm

Chromeで https://example.com/ にアクセスしたところ、リクエストヘッダにHostはありませんでした。
[image: Chromeのネットワーク]

Firefoxで https://example.com/ にアクセスすると、リクエストヘッダにHostはありました。
[image: Firefox]

## 質問

Chromeで https://example.com/ にアクセスしたときには、なぜHostリクエストヘッダが付与されないのでしょうか？
https://example.com/ はHTTP/2で通信していました。
HTTP/2ではHostリクエストヘッダはオプショナルのでしょうか？
`http2 host header`などのワードでGoogle検索してみましたが、Hostヘッダが必須なのかどうかが分かりませんでした。

http://developer.hatena.ne.jp/ にChromeでアクセスする（HTTP/1.1）と、Hostリクエストヘッダが付与されていました。
[image: Chromeでdeveloper.hatena.ne.jpにアクセスしたときの通信]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HTTP/2では、「:authority疑似ヘッダがあればHostヘッダは必須ではない」ということでしょうか？

Hostヘッダは「必須ではない」のではなく、「推奨されていない」と理解しています。

先のRFCを再掲します。

[rfc7540 section-8.1.2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.3)

> Clients that generate HTTP/2 requests directly SHOULD use the ":authority" pseudo-header field instead of the Host header field.

訳

> HTTP/2リクエストを直接生成するクライアントは、Hostヘッダーフィールドの代わりに ":authority" 擬似ヘッダーフィールドを使用**すべきである**。

この仕様は`SHOULD`なので、Requirement Levelは「推奨」です。

[rfc2119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119#section-3)

> SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item, but the full implications must be understood and carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

以上から、私は次のように理解しています。

- HTTP/2では、`:authority`疑似ヘッダの利用が推奨される
- Hostヘッダの利用は禁止されてはいないが、`:authority`疑似ヘッダの利用が推奨される以上、原則使うべきではない

Comment: 勝手ながら、異なる回答ではなく補足なので、元の回答に追記された方が内容が分断されなくていいかなと思いました。

Comment: なるほど。次からそうします。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

> Chromeで https://example.com/ にアクセスしたときには、なぜHostリクエストヘッダが付与されないのでしょうか？
> https://example.com/ はHTTP/2で通信していました。
> HTTP/2ではHostリクエストヘッダはオプショナルのでしょうか？

HTTP/2では、`HOST`リクエストヘッダの代わりに`:authority`疑似ヘッダを使います。

[rfc7540 section-8.1.2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.3)

> Clients that generate HTTP/2 requests directly SHOULD use the ":authority" pseudo-header field instead of the Host header field.

１枚目のスクリーンショットをみると、`:authority`で`example.com`が指定されています。

Comment: HTTP/2では、「:authority疑似ヘッダがあればHostヘッダは必須ではない」ということでしょうか？